# Is there a way to send (wcf rest) json request content from fiddler into an object type on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to use Fiddler to send a wcf rest request but not having any luck. I was wondering if it's possible to send json to resource that accepts an object type (like MyClass below). Or will I have to convert it manually somehow? I don't know if my Request Body is correct or even possible?

Here's the Reques Body in Fiddler I'm using:

```
{"jsonUser": "MyClass:{Email:someemail@hotmail.com}"}
```

Here's the server side

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
}

[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="/users")]
[OperationContract]
public void AddUser(MyClass jsonUser)
{
   //blah
}
```

**The error I keep getting is:**
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter :jsonUser. The InnerException message was 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part)

**Update** I know this somewhat works because if I change the MyClass parameter to be a string:

```
public void AddUser(string jsonUser)
{
   //blah
}
```

**Request Body:**

```
{"jsonUser":"{Email:some.email@hotmail.com}"}
```

**Request Headers**

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept-Language: en-US
Host: localhost:52598
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: blah
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 44
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try? { "Email": "someemail@hotmail.com" } I think your json is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json is not formatted correctly. I believe it should be

```
{"Email":"someemail@hotmail.com"}
```

Have you tried going the other way and serializing it? Having copied you class definition and serialized it, this json is what you get out. The parameter name is not supposed to be in the json.

Comment: updated my OP with some evidence that it's somewhat working.

Comment: Have you tried this json though? Don't include the "jsonUser", send only what both I and Mariusz wrote. I see you also changed the function parameter to string. That changes it. It should work if you keep it as MyClass and use this json.

Comment: I don't get any request errors but jsonUser parameter is null.

Comment: I think I got it! {"jsonUser":{"Email":"some.email@hotmail.com"}}, Thanks guys!

Comment: so I should be able to send json to object type for "free" minus headache